# MVC form moves when it is validated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.beginform

I have created an MVC form.
Everything is working fine, however, when error messages are displayed, they move form to the left.

This is a code:

```
<div style="text-align: center; padding-top: 40px;">
     <h2 style="color: white;">Title</h2>

        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <div>
                @Html.EditorForModel()
                <p><input type="submit" class="k-primary" value="Log In" /></p>
            </div>
        }
</div>
```

This is my Edit Template:

```
<div style="margin: 0px auto; text-align: center; display: table;">
    <table>
        <tr>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "username" } })</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.UserName,"", new { @class = "text-danger"})</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "password" } })</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Password)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height:70px;">
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" class="k-primary" value="Log In" /></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

This is the generated code:

[image: I tried to style the <code>div</code> around t]he form as `position:fixed`. It did not fix it

What am I missing, so the form does not move anywhere and stays fixed?

Comment: The best way for you to find it is to use the Console to see what new CSS gets applied when it gets validated. We can't help you if all you show is `@Html.EditorForModel()`. There is so much that can be in there, and any CSS that would alter the layout of the DOM. We can't help without seeing what you're sending to the browser.

Comment: I just updated the post with the code